# Limit date range in Joda Time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am using Joda Time library for parsing the string into dateTime using parseDateTime funtion in this library  and noticed that date range supported for this library is -292,269,054 to 292,277,023.

Can anyone know on how to limit date range using this library.Especially with year (YYYY) to 9999?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that a requirement (or responsibility) of the library, that would come down to you providing that functionality based on your needs - mind you, you could probably implement one of the date classes yourself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `Interval` Class

You can limit date ranges in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) with [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html).

You can then query whether a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is within that interval/range.

Answer (score 1):

As [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) commented, limiting a date range is your job as the app developer. Joda-Time cannot know what you consider to be reasonable limits.

## Bean Validation

To help with that chore of validating data, you might find the [Bean Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation) spec useful. Defined by JSR 303 ([spec 1.0](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/)) and [JSR 349](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349) ([spec 1.1)](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/).

With Bean Validation, you can conveniently use annotations to define rules such as a minimum and maximum value for a particular member variable in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Joda-Time surprisingly offers what you want (really?). The apparent solution is using [LimitChronology](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/LimitChronology.html). An example:

```
DateTime min = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0);
DateTime max = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0).minusMillis(1);
Chronology chronology = 
  LimitChronology.getInstance(ISOChronology.getInstance(), min, max);

DateTime now = DateTime.now(chronology);
System.out.println(now.toString(DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime()));
// output: Donnerstag, 6. November 2014 19:08 Uhr MEZ

DateTime test = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0).withChronology(chronology);
System.out.println(test.toString(DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime()));
// no exception! => output: �, �. � ���� ��:�� Uhr MEZ

test = now.withYear(1970);
// IllegalArgumentException: 
// The resulting instant is below the supported minimum of 
// 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 (ISOChronology[Europe/Berlin])
```

**My advise is however not to use this feature.**

First reason is the inconvenience to apply the `LimitChronology` on every `DateTime`-object in your program. Probably you would be forced to change your application architecture to install a central factory for producing such exotic `DateTime`-objects in order to be sure that you really don't forget any object.

Another reason is the partial unreliability of the chronology in question. It can not prevent instantiating `DateTime`-objects outside of the supported limited range but produces strange formatted output (see example above).

Therefore I suggest you to follow the advise of @MadProgrammer or @CharlieS using `Interval` for range checks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can test with this code

```
DateTime startRange = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endRange = new DateTime(9999, 12, 31, 21, 59, 59, 59);
Interval interval = new Interval(startRange, endRange);
DateTime testRange = new DateTime(2014, 10, 30, 11, 0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(interval.contains(testRange)); // returns true

endRange = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 21, 59, 59, 59);
testRange = new DateTime(9999, 10, 30, 11, 0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(interval.contains(testRange)); // returns false
```